# Merging unregistered User "S Halayka"

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

The unregistered user "S Halayka" appears twice: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26451/s-halayka) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26455/s-halayka).

Is it possible to merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. For future reference, flagging (as you have done also) is sufficient for this. You don't have to open a new thread up on Meta. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll do. Thanks

Comment: Willie... flagging *what*, exactly? [This guy](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/26102/michael-sink) and [this other guy](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/24538/michael-sink) are the same.

Comment: @TheChaz: flag one of their answers/questions, and give links (or at least user ids) of both (or more) of the accounts. It is easiest if you flag one Q/A on which both of the accounts were used.